# Identifying the antipodal points of one boundary of the cylinder gives the Möbius band.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

In Example 1.35, Hatcher writes in his book *Algebraic Topology*, the following (not paraphrased):

> Let $X=S^1\times I$, and let $A$ be the quotient space obtained by defining the relation $(z, 0)\sim (e^{i\pi}z, 0)$ on $X$. Then $A$ is the Möbius band.

That is, if we identity the antipodal points on $S^1\times \{0\}$, we get the Möbius band.

I am unable to prove this. The definition of the Möbius band which I am using is the one where we identify the points $(x, 0)$ with $(1-x, 1)$ in the square $I\times I$.

I tried to "open" the cylinder by cutting along a line parallel to the axis of the cylinder. This gives us a square, and an induced equivalence relation on the square. But it doesn't look anything like the Möbius band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a fundamental polygon of your space. This is a pentagon say with sides $a,b,c,d,e$ with sides $c,e$ identified in an orientation preserving manner and $a,b$ in reverse orientation. Now cut the pentagon by the line joining the vertex where $a,b$ meet and the midpoint of segment $d$. What do you get?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see why the two spaces are equal now. But how did you think of this?

Comment: @caffeinemachine Whenever you can draw something as quotient of the square, try cutting it up and glueing back consistently to get something you already know about. In this case, the idea is to get the red lines to be opposite to each other.

Comment: Another way to think of this is as a projective plane minus a disk. This is explained in the chapter on connected sums in Jeffrey Week's Space of Space.